# No Matching Function for call to

Tags: c++, marmalade

I am new to Marmalade, and am trying to get to grips with the unusual formatting and so forth, and am struggling to see why it keeps throwing an error.

I am trying to get it to display my UI which I have defined, likely incorrectly, but in the correct format atleast. And yet I keep getting:

"error : no matching function for call to 'CIwUISlot1 >::CIwUISlot1(CController* const, const char [23], void (CController::*)())'"

Which I can not solve, I have seen it  can be caused by incorrect variables being passed, but as far as I can see they are right. Here is the code from IwUIElementSignal.h:

```
#define IW_UI_CREATE_VIEW_SLOT1(Owner, Name, Class, Member, Param1) {       \
IDelegateQuery* pSlot =                                                     \
new CIwUISlot1<Class, Param1>(Owner, #Member, &Class::Member);              \
IwGetUIView()->AddDelegate(IwHashString(#Class), IwHashString(Name), pSlot); }
```

Which is called from Main.cpp as such:

```
class CController : public CIwUIController
{
public:
    CController()
    {
        IW_UI_CREATE_VIEW_SLOT1(this, "CController", CController, OnClickButton_Quotes, CIwUIElement*)
        IW_UI_CREATE_VIEW_SLOT1(this, "CController", CController, OnClickButton_Targets, CIwUIElement*)
        IW_UI_CREATE_VIEW_SLOT1(this, "CController", CController, OnClickButton_Add_Entry, CIwUIElement*)
        IW_UI_CREATE_VIEW_SLOT1(this, "CController", CController, OnClickButton_Backup, CIwUIElement*)
        IW_UI_CREATE_VIEW_SLOT1(this, "CController", CController, OnClickButton_Clock, CIwUIElement*)
        IW_UI_CREATE_VIEW_SLOT1(this, "CController", CController, OnClickButton_Postit_1, CIwUIElement*)
    }

private:
    void OnClickButton_Quotes()
    {

}
void OnClickButton_Targets()
{

}
void OnClickButton_Add_Event()
{

}
void OnClickButton_Clock()
{

}
void OnClickButton_Backup()
{

}
void OnClickButton_Postit_1()
{

}
};
```

This is particularly perplexing as it more or less copied and pasted from the IwUI examples which come with the Marmalade SDK...

Please could you be detailed in your response, as I am not only new to Marmalade but also C++.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

All the event handling functions should take CIwUIElement* as their parameter. So the function declarations should be following:

```
void OnClickButton_Quotes(CIwUIElement*)
{

}

void OnClickButton_Targets(CIwUIElement*)
{

}
```

... e.t.c.